# Launch Bootstrap Modal on page load NOT working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know javascript and I am very new to this.  I am trying to add a bootstrap modal in page load but it's not working for me.  Here is the code I've got:

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Modal -->


  <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
      <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Body text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

The error I get is this:

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (bootstrap.js, line 0)
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$('#myModal').modal('show')')
    (anonymous function) (antiquities-of-nubia, line 7)
    dispatch (jquery.js, line 4641)
    handle (jquery.js, line 4309)

What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I hope this is enough information so I don't get negative points.  I am not sure how else to ask a question so I don't get marked down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also some missing classes on your html. I've changed your code and it is working fine now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"     src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
 </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Modal -->

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great thank you.  Yes, this is working but how do I make this pop up over my actual page like on this page? http://neatline.dclure.org/neatline/show/declaration-of-independence

Comment: Just put your page content code right after <body> tag. Or you can also copy the example to your existing page!

Comment: The thing is that I am using Omeka (CMS to create digital collections) and Neatline (Omeka Plugin).  So, I don't have an html page.  I am not sure how I can do that.  I know it can be done because the page I posted above (neatline.dclure.org/neatline/show/declaration-of-independence) is also using Omeka and Neatline.  I looked at the files for that website on Github and still can't figure out how it's done (https://github.com/davidmcclure/neatlight/tree/master/neatline/exhibits/themes/declaration-of-independence).  I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry I don't know Omeka. But in order to put it to work you have to find a way to add the HTML in your page. I can see that you can do it by creating a plugin. I would create another topic on omeka area asking how to do it.

Comment: Thanks.  I already asked there and didn't really get any responses.  This is what I got from a guy who did the same thing: "Easiest would be to put the markup for the modal in a custom show.php file - take a look at some of the exhibit themes I've built for examples of how to structure that file:

https://github.com/davidmcclur...

And then add a script.js file to your exhibit theme, and put the code to initialize the modal there."  Unfortunately, I don't know what to put where.  Which code would I put in script.js, for example?

Answer (score 2):

As per the error, `bootstrap.js` itself is not getting loaded.
In case you are interested in CDN links for bootstrap, I have pasted them below (copied as provided in `http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download` )

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes, I see that. What would be the reason it's not getting loaded?  Where do I need to put it?  I have it located in the same directory as my show.php file which contains the code I posted.  Thank you.  I realize my question is basic but I am really new to this.

Comment: Probably the directory is not at the root directory of your web-app. In that case, you need to update the `src` in the <script> tag to match the relative path.

Comment: I just included CDN links instead and don't get any error messages any more but it's still not working. You can see it here http://54.81.134.147/omeka/neatline/show/antiquities-of-nubia